# How to start programming with 24 bit (any 24 series)pic microcontroller?

Tags: pic, pic24

I have programmed pic with  8 bit micro controller. Can anyone suggest me the reference manuals , example code for 24 bit series....?

Comment: GIYF: http://www.engscope.com/pic24-tutorial/

Comment: Small point, but the PIC24 range are 16-bit not 24-bit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the [XC16 compiler](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/devtools/mplabxc/home.html) from microchip website. Inside it you'll find some pdf with all compilers informations. Also check on microchip website for other pdf about it

[Deid](http://www.deid.it/learn)

Answer (score 0):

- Download the [MPLAB X IDE](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/family/mplabx/).
- Download the [XC16 compiler](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/devtools/mplabxc/home.html).
- Download the datasheet for the part you have.
- Download one of the many [application notes](http://www.microchip.com/wwwcategory/TaxonomySearch.aspx?show=Application%20Notes) for the PIC24.